# Issue with Apache2 Reverse proxy

Tags: networking, apache2, reverse-proxy, virtualhost

I need to create a reverse proxy in apache2 for an icecast server, but with another virtualhost as a simple website

I managed to create the reverse proxy, using this configuration in apache Virtualhost

```
<VirtualHost 100.100.100.100:80>
    ServerName icecast.xxx.com
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8000/
</VirtualHost>
```

100.100.100.100 is the ip of the server, and xxx.com is the domain
So when i type in my browser `icecast.xxx.com` the icecast admin panel (on 8000 port) show up

Then i have added another virtualhost

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName xxx.com
        ServerAlias www.xxx.com
        ServerAdmin MY_EMAIL
        DocumentRoot /var/www/site/html

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I have enabled him with `sudo a2ensite NAME_OF_THE_CONFIG_FILE`

But when I go to the ip of the VPS or to `xxx.com`/`www.xxx.com` the icecast2 admin panel show up!

I don't know how to solve this, I maybe think that the error is in the  line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to solve the issue,
simply in the reverse proxy virtualhost, instead of `<VirtualHost 100.100.100.100:80>`
I need to put
`<VirtualHost *:80>`